# How to set zoom level for excel sheet using epplus library?

Tags: c#, epplus

It looks like very basic thing but i am not able to find property of epplus that allows me to set sheet zoom level. I have tried below property:

```
workSheet.PrinterSettings.Scale
```

But it did not set the zoom level of excel sheet. Looking forward for suggestions..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to access the property via the worksheet `View` like this:

```
worksheet.View.ZoomScale = 250;
```

The above would set it to a scale of 250% in this case.